# passing openssl_encrypt encrypted data as query string

Tags: php, encryption

I am using openssl_encrypt and openssl_decrypt functions to encrypt and decrypt the id passed as querystring. But in some cases the encrypted query string contains '+' character. which causes problem in the openssl_decrypt function  and I gets the following warning.

```
$x = openssl_encrypt ('3', 'AES-256-CBC', $password,0, $iv);
echo openssl_decrypt ($x, 'AES-256-CBC', $password,0, $iv);
```

**Warning:  openssl_decrypt(): Failed to base64 decode the input**

Please let me know if there is any other method to encrypt data without this '+' characters. Also I want to limit the character length of the encrypted id below 100.

Comment: You may want to use CRC32 if you are using rdbms ? there is no need to encrypt decrypt just pass your id crc32 encoded and match with crc32 or when selecting fetch with crc32(id) but this suggestion is for if your aim is shadow your real ids from public.

Answer (score 2):

There are characters that must be URL-encoded in a query string so the query string must be un-encoded prior to use. What you are probably seeing is the space character being encoded as "+".

See [URL encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string#URL_encoding) -  *wikipedia*.

HTML 5 specifies the following transformation for submitting HTML forms with the "get" method to a web server:[1]

Characters that cannot be converted to the correct charset are replaced with HTML numeric character references[11]

- SPACE is encoded as '+' or '%20'
- Letters (A–Z and a–z), numbers (0–9) and the characters '*','-','.' and '_' are left as-is
- All other characters are encoded as %HH hex representation with any non-ASCII characters first encoded as UTF-8 (or other specified encoding)

Comment: What's a `quarry`? Is it eatable? :-)

Comment: @CharlotteDunois No, it is swung over one's head.

Answer (score 1):

> I am using openssl_encrypt and openssl_decrypt functions to encrypt and decrypt the id passed as querystring.

Can I introduce you to [a better idea than encrypting IDs](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/09/comprehensive-guide-url-parameter-encryption-in-php)?

> ```
> $x = openssl_encrypt ('3', 'AES-256-CBC', $password,0, $iv);
> echo openssl_decrypt ($x, 'AES-256-CBC', $password,0, $iv);
> ```

Two things:

1. [Authenticate your ciphertext](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/05/using-encryption-and-authentication-correctly).
2. Use `OPENSSL_RAW_DATA` or `urlencode()` it.

Answer (score 0):

1) Use OPENSSL_RAW_DATA 
2)  iv (A non-NULL Initialization Vector) should be some alphanumeric.
for example 
$iv="0123456789abcdef";